# How to filter empty fields in rich column

Tags: richfaces, filtering

I have an extendedDataTable with columns that may contain empty fields and I want to filter somehow these empty fields. Any ideas?

Below one of my columns:

```
    <rich:column sortBy="#{service.primaryName.label}"
        filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:containsIgnoreCase(service.primaryName.label, filterValue)}"
        filterValue="#{serviceFilteringBean.servPrimary}">
        <f:facet name="header">#{lbl.service_design_pending_services_list_primary}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{service.primaryName.label}" />
    </rich:column>
```

Comment: Please add some source code to display your progress and to help us understand and pin point your problems better

Comment: Did you try use `#{empty serviceFilteringBean.servPrimary ...}` instead of `filterValue` (I don't know if this variable is accessible just like that)?